# Mod Rewrite Subdirectory to Subdomain (without redirect)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I'm trying to rewrite URLs (without an external redirect) from:

```
http://example.com/support/anything/goes/here
```

to

```
http://support.example.com/anything/goes/here
```

This works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^support/(.*)$ http://support.example.com/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

except that it does an actual redirect. I've tried using the P flag, but this causes a server error. Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible?

Comment: possible if you can make changes in server config.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to do it from htaccess? Could you provide more information on the changes needed to the httpd config?